# rvm error when create new app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, reinstall

I just reinstalled rvm, ruby and rails. Installation ran fine.

But, whenever I create a new rails app, I always get an error:

```
$ rails new abc
  create  
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  ...

  create  vendor/plugins
  create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
     run  bundle install
/Users/kong/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0038 p:---- s:0217 b:0217 l:000216 d:000216 CFUNC  :connect
c:0037 p:0011 s:0214 b:0214 l:0006b0 d:000213 BLOCK  /Users/kong/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799
```

I think by somehow, I messed up with rvm installation.
I tried to reinstall rvm and rails many times, but it just get same error.

I can install rvm and rails in another user account. It works fine but not so convenient for me.

Anyone know how to have a fresh reinstalled rvm? I try `rvm implode` but still get that error.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried `rm -rf ~/.rvm` ?

Comment: yes, I did, and error is still there. I guest problem may be in other packages I installed in my user account. Don't know if imagemagick or any others can cause problem?

Answer (score 0):

please read `rvm requirements` ruby-1.9.3-p125 was not fully compatibile with LLVM, try installaing osx-gcc-installer and reinstall ruby:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p125
```

Also please note that the current patchlevel for 1.9.3 is 194:

```
rvm get head
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Comment: I tried many time with p194, then switch back to p125, because I used to be successful with p125. Anyway, none of them work for me now. I uninstall XCode and install osx-gcc-installer too. Still not work :(

Comment: what does it mean no go? the error message you posted should change for GNU GCC, please post new one or make sure osx-gcc-installer was installed correctly.

Comment: after days messing up with `rvm`, I decided to go for `rbenv`. It just works for me now. Can you recommend `rbenv` in your answer too?